# Can you use make to process command line specified files?

Tags: shell, makefile

This is exactly what I want to do: I wonder if I can define a rule in make, such that I can provide make a .o file through the command line, and then that command line will be processed with the command

```
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D <object file>
```

The idea is to simplify debugging by not having  to do that command by hand but rather do something like:

```
debug file.o
```

If make can't do this is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of. You can create a rule like:

```
%.dump : %.o; arm-none-eabi-objdump -D $^
```

then do:

```
$ make file.dump
```

hth

Comment: this is close enough :p